# Android custom keyboard layouts switching

Tags: android, layout, keyboard

I want to develop my own keyboard. I do it like it explained at [here](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-create-a-system-keyboard-on-android-95aca21b1e5f)

This works like a charm when I use only one keyboard layout. If I want to use two layouts and switch between them something strange happens with layouts.

[letter keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aoq9Q.png) 
Everything is fine in pic1 and now I am switching to symbols keyboard layout.
[symbols keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUm1H.png)
But here we can see that right key buttons exit from the right border.
Now switch keyboard layout back to the letters keyboard and see that
the right column disappeared entirely.
[letters keyboard 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA9Jq.png)
How can I fix this issue?

Keyboard layouts look like that

keys_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:keyHeight="60dp"
    android:horizontalGap="3px"
    android:verticalGap="3px"
    android:keyTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:keyBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1081" android:keyLabel="й" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1094" android:keyLabel="ц"/>
        <Key android:codes="1091" android:keyLabel="у" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupkeyboard_template" android:popupCharacters="@string/alternates_for_y"/>
        <Key android:codes="1082" android:keyLabel="к"/>
        <Key android:codes="1077" android:keyLabel="е" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupkeyboard_template" android:popupCharacters="@string/alternates_for_e"/>
        <Key android:codes="1085" android:keyLabel="н"/>
        <Key android:codes="1075" android:keyLabel="г"/>
        <Key android:codes="1096" android:keyLabel="ш"/>
        <Key android:codes="1097" android:keyLabel="щ"/>
        <Key android:codes="1079" android:keyLabel="з"/>
        <Key android:codes="1093" android:keyLabel="х" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="1092" android:keyLabel="ф" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1099" android:keyLabel="ы"/>
        <Key android:codes="1074" android:keyLabel="в"/>
        <Key android:codes="1072" android:keyLabel="а" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupkeyboard_template" android:popupCharacters="@string/alternates_for_a"/>
        <Key android:codes="1087" android:keyLabel="п"/>
        <Key android:codes="1088" android:keyLabel="р"/>
        <Key android:codes="1086" android:keyLabel="о"/>
        <Key android:codes="1083" android:keyLabel="л"/>
        <Key android:codes="1076" android:keyLabel="д"/>
        <Key android:codes="1078" android:keyLabel="ж"/>
        <Key android:codes="1101" android:keyLabel="э" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="-1"  android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="1103" android:keyLabel="я"/>
        <Key android:codes="1095" android:keyLabel="ч"/>
        <Key android:codes="1089" android:keyLabel="с" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupkeyboard_template" android:popupCharacters="@string/alternates_for_c"/>
        <Key android:codes="1084" android:keyLabel="м"/>
        <Key android:codes="1080" android:keyLabel="и"/>
        <Key android:codes="1090" android:keyLabel="т"/>
        <Key android:codes="1100" android:keyLabel="ь" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popupkeyboard_template" android:popupCharacters="@string/alternates_for_hard_sign"/>
        <Key android:codes="1073" android:keyLabel="б"/>
        <Key android:codes="1102" android:keyLabel="ю"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_backspace" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyLabel="\?123" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/"/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="@string/keyboard_space" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyBackground="@color/colorPrimary" android:keyLabel="@string/keyboard_search" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

symbols_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:keyHeight="60dp"
    android:horizontalGap="3px"
    android:verticalGap="3px"
    android:keyTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:keyBackground="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="1" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="50" android:keyLabel="2"/>
        <Key android:codes="51" android:keyLabel="3"/>
        <Key android:codes="52" android:keyLabel="4"/>
        <Key android:codes="53" android:keyLabel="5"/>
        <Key android:codes="54" android:keyLabel="6"/>
        <Key android:codes="55" android:keyLabel="7"/>
        <Key android:codes="56" android:keyLabel="8"/>
        <Key android:codes="57" android:keyLabel="9"/>
        <Key android:codes="48" android:keyLabel="0" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="64" android:keyLabel="\@" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="35" android:keyLabel="#"/>
        <Key android:codes="36" android:keyLabel="$"/>
        <Key android:codes="37" android:keyLabel="%"/>
        <Key android:codes="38" android:keyLabel="&amp;"/>
        <Key android:codes="45" android:keyLabel="-"/>
        <Key android:codes="43" android:keyLabel="+"/>
        <Key android:codes="40" android:keyLabel="("/>
        <Key android:codes="41" android:keyLabel=")"/>
        <Key android:codes="91" android:keyLabel="[" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Key android:codes="42" android:keyLabel="*" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="34" android:keyLabel="&quot;"/>
        <Key android:codes="39" android:keyLabel="'"/>
        <Key android:codes="58" android:keyLabel=":"/>
        <Key android:codes="59" android:keyLabel=";"/>
        <Key android:codes="33" android:keyLabel="!"/>
        <Key android:codes="63" android:keyLabel="\?"/>
        <Key android:codes="93" android:keyLabel="]"/>
        <Key android:codes="-5" android:keyIcon="@drawable/ic_backspace" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">
        <Key android:codes="0" android:keyLabel="АБВ" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
        <Key android:codes="47" android:keyLabel="/"/>
        <Key android:codes="32" android:keyLabel="@string/keyboard_space" android:keyWidth="40%p" android:isRepeatable="true"/>
        <Key android:codes="46" android:keyLabel="."/>
        <Key android:codes="-4" android:keyBackground="@color/colorPrimary" android:keyLabel="@string/keyboard_search" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right"/>
    </Row>
</Keyboard>
```

I switch keyboard layouts like this way

```
        case 0:
            if (iKeyboardType == 1) {
                keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.symbols_layout);
                iKeyboardType = 2;
            }
            else if (iKeyboardType == 2){
                keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.keys_layout);
                iKeyboardType = 1;
            }
            keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            keyboardView.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any correct solution so I did it on my own way. If keys in both layouts have the same size then everything works fine and keys do not go outside. Maybe it will helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue, but not sure if it's the same. What I did was that I ensure that the android keywidth of each button in a row is not more than `100%p`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0dp"
    android:verticalGap="0dp"
    android:keyHeight="60dp">

    <Row>
    <Key android:keyLabel="1"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
        android:codes="49" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="2"
        android:codes="50" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="3"
        android:codes="51" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="4"
        android:codes="52" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="5"
        android:codes="53" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="6"
        android:codes="54" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="7"
        android:codes="55" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="8"
        android:codes="56" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="9"
        android:codes="57" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
    <Key android:keyLabel="0"
        android:keyEdgeFlags="right"
        android:codes="48" android:keyWidth="10%p"  />
</Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel="q" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:codes="113" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="w" android:codes="119" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="e" android:codes="101" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="r" android:codes="114" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="t" android:codes="116" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="y" android:codes="121" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="u" android:codes="117" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="i" android:codes="105" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="o" android:codes="111" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:codes="112" android:keyWidth="10%p" />
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel="a" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:codes="97" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="s" android:codes="115" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="d" android:codes="100" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="f" android:codes="102" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="g" android:codes="103" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="h" android:codes="104" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="j" android:codes="106" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="k" android:codes="107" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="l" android:codes="108" android:keyWidth="11.1%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />
<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="\#" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:codes="35" />-->
    </Row>

    <Row>
        <Key android:keyLabel="CAP" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:codes="-1" android:keyWidth="12%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="z" android:codes="122" android:keyWidth="10.8%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="x" android:codes="120" android:keyWidth="10.8%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="c" android:codes="99" android:keyWidth="10.8%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="v" android:codes="118" android:keyWidth="10.8%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="b" android:codes="98" android:keyWidth="10.8%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="n" android:codes="110" android:keyWidth="10.8%p" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="m" android:codes="109" android:keyWidth="10.8%p" />
<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="." android:codes="46" />-->
<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="\:" android:keyWidth="10%p" android:codes="58" />-->
        <Key android:keyLabel="DEL"  android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:isRepeatable="true" android:keyWidth="12%p" android:codes="-5" />
<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="\! :" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:codes="33, 58" />-->
<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="\? ! :" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:codes="63, 33, 58" />-->
    </Row>

    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="bottom">

<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="/" android:keyWidth="10%p"  android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:codes="47" />-->
<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="\!" android:keyWidth="10%p" android:codes="33" />-->
        <Key android:keyEdgeFlags="left" android:keyLabel="!#1" android:codes="-2" android:keyWidth="14%p"/>
        <Key android:keyLabel="," android:codes="44" android:keyWidth="11%p" />
<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="\@"  android:keyWidth="10%p" android:codes="64" />-->
        <Key android:keyLabel="SPACE" android:keyWidth="50%p" android:isRepeatable="true" android:codes="32" />
        <Key android:keyLabel="." android:codes="46" android:keyWidth="11%p" />
<!--        <Key android:keyLabel="\?" android:keyWidth="10%p" android:codes="63" />-->
        <Key android:keyLabel="DONE" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" android:codes="-4" android:keyWidth="14%p" />

    </Row>

</Keyboard>
```